# Add new content to JSP page without losing existing dynamically generated content

Tags: html, jsp

I am developing a basic web-application where after adding some input data on my first.jsp file, the data is processed via a servlet (say AnalyzeServlet.java) and resulting data is displayed in results.jsp. Here is how I am displaying the output in results.jsp file:

```
    <c:when test="${userChoice == 'student'}">
    <table border="1" width=100%>
    <th> STUDENT NUMBER</th>
    <th> STUDENT NAME</th>
    <th> STUDENT ADDRESS </th>
    <c:forEach items="${results}" var="result">
        <tr>
            <td>${result.number}</td>
            <td>${result.name}</td>
            <td>${result.address}</td>
         </tr>
    </c:forEach>
   </table>
  </c:when>
```

Below is the text box where an input is entered and clicking on Submit should get additional content.

```
     <div id="resultPageForm1">
<form name="BForm1" action="NewServlet" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="bChoice" value="grades">
    <h3> Paste name of a student in the text box and click on Submit to get grades</h3>
    <input type="text" name="input">
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="GET GRADES">
</form>
</div>
<h3>Grades are displayed below</h3>
<p>${Output1}</p>
```

I am providing the user with an option that a student name can be entered from the above output into a text box and upon clicking submit, the grades for this semester should be displayed in a text box (i.e. div). However, the key is that existing output (i.e. list of student number, address, name) should still be visible. However, currently, the grades are getting displayed and above data is getting lost and I have to press the back arrow on browser to retrieve this data. So my question is how can I update a current page that already has some dynamically generated content without losing it?

Comment: Should i redirect the jsp to a new servlet or parent servlet that generated existing data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this.

1. One approach would be to use AJAX.  AJAX is a technique for retrieving data from a server without reloading the web page.  Thus you would have a single page with both the form and the results section.  The form submit button would submit an AJAX call to your servlet to retrieve the results.  Then you would use JavaScript to dynamically update the results section of the page.  Given what you have now, this would be a significant change.  Plus is you don't know AJAX and Javascript, this will be difficult for you.
2. An approach that might fit better with what you have (a form JSP, a results JSP and a servlet) would be to use HTML frames.  This is an older technique and can be a bit less visually pleasing, but it should get the job done.  Here's a very quick overview:

a) Create a frame set as your main page.  On page will be for submitting the form.  One frame will be for displaying results:

```
<frameset rows="50%,50%">
    <frame  name="resultsFrame">
    <frame src="f2.html" name="formFrame">
</frameset>
```

b) In your formFrame, put your form.  Set the **target** attribute to point at the resultsFrame:

```
<form name="BForm1" action="NewServlet" method="POST" target="resultsFrame">
    <input type="hidden" name="bChoice" value="grades">
    <h3> Paste name of a student in the text box and click on Submit to get grades</h3>
    <input type="text" name="input">
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="GET GRADES">
</form>
```

When you submit the form, the results will appear in the other frame.

Comment: Good advice, I would definitely go with the JavaScript + AJAX though. Doing it via jQuery isn't too bad once you get the hang of it. 

@Newcoder, remember, JSPs are not dynamic, you need javascript for that (same with python, php, etc.).

Comment: Thanks much @EJK. I am currently learning web development and JAVA+AJAX is certainly on my radar. As of now, i have implemented the second approach and I can get the required output (although in a new window but again, considering my limited setup, this solution certainly works).